Instructing middleware not to log errors on its own
TL;DR: In my WebAPI app, how can I use IExceptionHandler and still prevent double logging issue?
What have I found searching:
ASP.NET Web API IExceptionLogger called twice
What have I tried:
Adding this to my app.settings didn't work eiter, although it is not even a good solution anyway.
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware": "None"

I have my own global error handler like this:
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandler: IExceptionHandler

which implements that one method it has: TryHandleAsync
The problem is it logs each error two times. One time using my own class and one time also Middleware on its own decides to log an error without even going to my method, so I want to tell middleware not to log its own.
Here is my program.cs: My feeling is that I should do more work regarding setting up that app.UseExceptionHandler part so middleware doesn't do its own thing. But I am not sure how it should be properly setup.
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<MyGlobalExceptionHandler>();
//
//
//
app.UseExceptionHandler(_ => { });

Like I said each error gets logged two times and even if I put breakpoints in my own class , it will only get hit one time so posting the whole code of my own class does not help because it does not even get hit two times. which means even before getting there, Middleware has already decided to log it its own which means I need more code in Program.cs  and I have already posted the two relevant lines of code I have in there.

Hi @Bohn, One time using my own class and one time also Middleware on its own decides to log an error without even going to my method, so I want to tell middleware not to log its own. the class means MyGlobalExceptionHandler, what does the middleware mean? Did you mean the first time you run the application the app.UseExceptionHandler will be hit and then if throw exception, the  MyGlobalExceptionHandler will be hit?

@Rena answer to your question: Yes, that's what I suspect is happening.  :Because I have no special logic inside this call app.UseExceptionHandler(_ => { });

Hi @Bohn, for why the middleware will be hit, this happens because the UseExceptionHandler middleware is being registered as part of the application's middleware pipeline. When the application starts, it goes through the middleware pipeline setup in the Program.cs file, and each middleware component is initialized and configured, including the UseExceptionHandler middleware.

Not an answer, but you can improve your code like this:
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<MyGlobalExceptionHandler>(); builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(); /* ... */ app.UseExceptionHandler(); // No need for empty lambda function
